Problem in understanding the boundary conditions of a Semi-infinite String with a Fixed End in a PDE course.
I am having trouble in understanding the following text given on the book , "Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers" by Lokenath Debnath and Tyn-Myint U:

We have just determined the solution of the initial-value problem for the infinite vibrating string. We will now study the effect of a boundary on the solution.
(A) Semi-infinite String with a Fixed End
Let us first consider a semi-infinite vibrating string with a fixed end, that is,
$$u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}, \quad 0 < x < \infty, \quad t > 0,$$
$$u(x,0) = f(x), \quad 0 \leq x < \infty,$$
$$u_t(x,0) = g(x), \quad 0 \leq x < \infty,$$
$$u(0,t) = 0, \quad 0 \leq t < \infty.$$
It is evident here that the boundary condition at  produces a wave moving to the right with the velocity $c.$ Thus, for $x>ct$ , the solution is the same as that of the infinite string, and the displacement is influenced only by the initial data on the interval $[x-ct,x+ct],$ as shown in Figure 5.4.1.


However, I don't get how do they say,
"It is evident here that the boundary condition at  produces a wave moving to the right with the velocity $c.$" ?
Also, the claim made by the following statement seems very confusing to me,
"Thus, for $x>ct$ , the solution is the same as that of the infinite string, and the displacement is influenced only by the initial data on the interval $[x-ct,x+ct],$ as shown in Figure 5.4.1."
I don't understand how to relate the figure and the claim in the quoted statement above to make sense out of the whole paragraph. Any help regarding this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Well, in the wave equation, all waves move with velocity $c$. In the case of a semi-infinite string they all (eventually) end up moving right, because any waves that move left will collide with the left end of the domain eventually and will be reflected to the right.
